# Чистка /var/tmp + /var/cache

Tags: linux, fedora

В общем, острая нехватка места в системном каталоге. Из 42 Гб доступно 2,2 Гб. Сносил, что только мог и что пока не нужно. `dnf autoremove` и т.д. - не помогло, высвободилось немного места и стало доступно 2,5 Гб.

---

**Если кратко:**

```
20G /var
20G вместе
9,9G /var/tmp
6,9G /var/cache
2,4G /var/log
....

9,9G    /var/tmp
9,9G    вместе
9,1G    /var/tmp/rMD-session-2835
501M    /var/tmp/abrt
205M    /var/tmp/dnf-ekkl-azt2a45o
11M /var/tmp/kdecache-ekkl
```

**/var/cache:**

```
]# du . -hcd 1 | sort -hr
6,9G    загалом
6,9G    .
5,5G    ./PackageKit
1,2G    ./yum
189M    ./dnf
14M     ./cups
6,6M    ./man
6,5M    ./akmods
1,5M    ./app-info
160K    ./ldconfig
128K    ./ibus
36K     ./php-pear
8,0K    ./realmd
8,0K    ./libX11
8,0K    ./krb5rcache
8,0K    ./httpd
8,0K    ./abrt-di
4,0K    ./lightdm
4,0K    ./gdm
4,0K    ./alchemist
```

**/var/tmp:**

```
]# du . -hcd 1 | sort -hr
9,9G    загалом
9,9G    .
9,1G    ./rMD-session-2835
501M    ./abrt
205M    ./dnf-ekkl-azt2a45o
11M ./kdecache-ekkl
6,6M    ./rMD-session-2888
5,4M    ./rMD-session-3075
8,0K    ./systemd-private-56b851ee533342d39646787ad77e8b09-rtkit-daemon.service-1ouSYT
8,0K    ./systemd-private-56b851ee533342d39646787ad77e8b09-httpd.service-8HMA06
8,0K    ./systemd-private-56b851ee533342d39646787ad77e8b09-colord.service-ObUKI0
8,0K    ./systemd-private-56b851ee533342d39646787ad77e8b09-chronyd.service-dFVQFX
4,0K    ./mc-root
4,0K    ./mc-ekkl
```

---

#### Что можно почистить и как?

Остальное не так критично. Ну ещё и `/var/log` 2.4 Гб.

Comment: Как минимум `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` точно можно, остальное зависит от содержимого каталогов (не помню его наизусть)

Comment: Да, кстати, у меня Федора. Самая большая директория /var/cache/PackageKit — 5,9 Гб и /var/cache/yum 1,2 Гб

Comment: Оу, да, до меня не сразу дошло, что надо было дистрибутив спросить) Но содержимое и размеры `/var/cache` и `/var/tmp` лучше тоже покажите, а то, возможно, не я один не помню наизусть, что там может быть, к тому же это зависит от установленных программ

Comment: @andreymal, добавил в текст вопроса, так лучше будет читаться.

Comment: Из `/var/tmp` можно сносить всё (желательно после этого перезагрузиться). Удалять можно простым `rm`'ом.  В `/var/cache` `PackageKit` и `yum` тоже скорей всего можно вычистить, но стоит быть более осторожным.

Comment: На будущее. Пользуйся `ncdu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиски дали вот что

```
]# du . -hcd 1 | sort -hr
....
9,1G    ./rMD-session-2835
6,6M    ./rMD-session-2888
5,4M    ./rMD-session-3075
....
```

**./rMD-session-XXXX** это временные директории (содержат много файлов) программы RecordMyDesktop. В силу каких-то причин они не удалились самой программой и легко удаляются вручную из-под обычного пользователя.

Кеш установочных пакетов, накопленных после многократных обновлений/переустановок чистятся так

```
]# pkcon refresh force -c -1
```

Ну а логи можно почистить, например так:

```
]# journalctl --vacuum-time=1d  # Где 1d означает сохранить логи за 1 день
```

Comment: Добавлю, найти самые большие папки: `du -kx | egrep -v "\./.+/" | sort -n`

Comment: А чем  "du . -hcd 1 | sort -hr" хуже?

Comment: ничем не хуже, как всегда вариантов много.

Comment: Ему просто хотелось показать свои знания ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Что можно почистить и как?

В линуксах есть такая утилита, называется она [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/).

Из Википедии:

> [Baobab](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baobab) - программа для анализа использования ёмкости разделов диска из состава свободной среды рабочего стола GNOME. Графически показывает, какие папки занимают больше места на диске. Начиная с версии 2.4.2 `Baobab` становится частью пакета `gnome-utils`.

---

From Wikipedia:

> [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer) - is a graphical disk usage analyzer for GNOME. It was part of `gnome-utils`, but was split off for GNOME 3.4. It was originally named `Baobab`. The software gives the user a menu-driven, graphical representation of what is on a disk drive. The interface allows for selection of specific parts of filesystem being scanned so a single folder, the entire filesystem, and even remote folders and filesystems can be scanned. The graphical representation can be switched between a ring chart and a treemap chart so the presentation can be tailored to the specific content being scanned.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Она ответит на вопрос «Что занимает место», а на вопрос «Что можно почистить» она не ответит — сдуру можно и какие-нибудь важные системные файлы потереть (скриншот у вас устаревший, кстати)

Comment: Да, но это не снимает вопроса: как удалять кеш?

Answer (score 0):

Если в других разделах диска места хватает, можно перекинуть символической ссылкой. Копируем содержимое папки в новую папку. Удаляем старые файлы. Создаём символическую ссылку со старой папки на новую. Гарантии не даю. Каталоги типа **/dev** не рекомендую переносить. Пример:

```
su
mkdir /bigharddrive/video
mv /home/alex/video/* /bigharddrive/video
ln -s /bigharddrive/video /home/alex
```

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Можно диск другой поставить, и монтировать его в /var и т.д. Но вопрос состоял в том, как ИЗБАВИТЬСЯ от мусора: ненужного кеша, временных файлов, которые на почистила сама программа, и логов.

Answer (score 0):

Очистить локальный репозиторий от мусора:

```
~# yum clean all
```